# How do I combine two columns within a dataframe in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have two columns, A and B, in my dataframe:

```
A  B
1  NaN
2  5
3  NaN
4  6
```

I want to get a new column, C, which fills in NaN cells in column B using values from column A:

```
A  B   C
1  NaN 1
2  5   5
3  NaN 3
4  6   6
```

How do I do this?

I'm sure this is a very basic question, but as I am new to Pandas, any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

You can use `combine_first`:

```
df['c'] = df['b'].combine_first(df['a'])
```

Docs: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.Series.combine_first.html

Comment: really elegant, this is the best solution!

Comment: most powerful way to do

Answer (score 5):

You can use `where` which is a vectorized if/else:

```
df['C'] = df['A'].where(df['B'].isnull(), df['B'])

   A   B  C
0  1 NaN  1
1  2   5  5
2  3 NaN  3
3  4   6  6
```

Comment: Thanks very much for pointing out the where clause, which seems useful for many other purposes as well. I have just looked at the documentation for it here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html. I am wondering what the inplace argument does. The description is somewhat obscure. Could anyone enlighten me?

Comment: you can simplify to this: `df['C'] = df.A.where(df.B.isnull(), df.B)` as `isnull` is available for df and series, also I wouldn't encourage the practice of accessing columns as attributes as it can lead to strange behaviour, better to do this `df['C'] = df['A'].where(df['B'].isnull(), df['B'])`

Comment: I edit my post, you are right on the accessing cols by attribute

Answer (score 2):

```
df['c'] = df['b'].fillna(df['a'])
```

So what .fillna will do is it will fill all the Nan values in the data frame
We can pass any value to it
Here we pass the value df['a']
So this method will put the corresponding values of 'a' into the Nan values of 'b' 
And the final answer will be in 'c'

Comment: This answer would benefit from a brief explanation of what `.fillna()` does, and perhaps a documentation link.